# Android - Disable text message notifications programmatically

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an application that handles text messages. This is a personal application and I do not plan to release it, however it's basically going to allow me to share my text messages (and phone number) between numerous devices through the internet. It's a fun learning project too as a first application, and I've done quite a lot.

However the annoying part is the text-message popup that my device gets when receiving a message. I love it when I'm using the device, and I could always just go into the options and disable the popup when I'm not planning on using the device, but I'm a very, very forgetful person and turning it back on wont always happen. Then I'll never reply to messages.

Basically I want to programmatically interrupt (or not even notify) my default messaging application of the text message, however I still want it to be logged in my messaging history. So the message can't just be "discarded". This should only happen of-course while my applications service is running.

I've been searching through the android API for quite some time and I just can't seem to figure this out, is it possible and if so can you link me to the proper place in the API to begin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basically I want to programmatically interrupt (or not even notify) my default messaging application of the text message...

This isn't possible.

Assuming by "interrupt" you mean to prevent the default SMS app from issuing its Notification, you can no more do this with the default app than you could with any other app that you don't control.

Additionally, as the default SMS app responds to the `SMS_DELIVER_ACTION` broadcast, and it is the only app to receive this broadcast, it wouldn't be possible to "not...notify" the default app of an incoming message. Your app wouldn't even have a chance to abort the broadcast, even if it were possible to do so.

(In versions prior to KitKat, it was oftentimes possible to register a Receiver with a high priority for the `SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION` broadcast, and then abort the broadcast before the native SMS app received it. This is what rajan ks's answer refers to.)

> ...however I still want it to be logged in my messaging history.

The default SMS app is responsible for writing all incoming messages to the Provider. Even if you were able to prevent the default app from receiving the incoming message, your app would then have to write the message itself. This isn't really possible, either, as the default app is the only one with standard write access to the Provider.

Comment: This is quite depressing, honestly. Thanks for the insight. Guess I'll just have to deal with killing 400 popups every now and again.

Comment: Yeah, the changes introduced in KitKat made it difficult/impossible to do certain things with SMS if your app isn't the default. You could always write your own full SMS client, but it's a sizeable task. Or, you might be able to find an open source SMS app, and tweak it to your needs. (This is probably what I'd do in your situation.) [QKSMS](https://github.com/qklabs/qksms) went open source recently.

Comment: Writing a SMS application isn't that much of a complication, I already have a really nice interface for it that's from one of my older applications using a WebView. I'll just do that! Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @MikeM. can we just disable notification sound for half second if SMS comes from a particular no. Plz answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527581/android-only-hide-notifications-for-smss-from-specific-sim-noi-know-i-cant-del here if possible