# only hide notifications for SMS from specific no or stop notification sound(or mute it) for 1-2 seconds?

Tags: android, notifications, sms, sendmessage, smsmanager

My application uses SMSs for data exchange between my android app and a device. The device will have a sim card in it, which will send a lot of regular SMSs to my App(i.e. to my paired sim no).

The issue is, a lot no messages are bothering my App users and they are getting irritated.

**I know, from KITKAT 4.4, I can't delete/write a SMS from provider. 
But can I just prevent notifications(specially voice), then vibration and then if possible status bar notification.**

And I don't want to create an entire SMS application as a default SMS app.

**I found a lot of question asking how to remove a SMS**, but I just want to prevent it bothering the user by **preventing/hiding notifications only**.

And if above not possible then can I create a default SMS app that will only read/receive SMS but for other parts like MMS and sending SMS's, will pass that functionality to other apps like default messaging app in device or hangout app etc.

Because **what I want is just to prevent notification when SMS comes from specific no**, let it then show in default SMS app.

***At least can i just stop notification sound(or mute it) for 1-2 seconds?***

Comment: can I create a 'SEMI' default SMS app that will only read/receive SMS but for other parts like MMS and sending SMS's, will pass that functionality to other apps like default messaging app in device or hangout app etc